# how to download activity log in json format instead of csv from azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I want to download activity log of resource group in json format instead of csv from azure portal.

I have tried checking on the google but did not find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) to view the JSON representation of your Azure resources.

Or you can also send the [Activity Log to Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log#send-to-azure-event-hubs) to send entries outside of Azure.

Activity log events from event hubs are consumed in JSON format with a records element containing the records in each payload. The schema depends on the category and is described in [Schema from storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-schema) and event hubs.

Take a look at the attached doc links for more info.

[image]

I reached out to the Product team to find more info here, as there is no direct way to download it from JSON.

I was told that you could send the activity logs to a log Analytics workspace and then probably use a log query to format the output in JSON. Since there is no specific option to export to JSON.

Comment: how to get activity logs of particular resource group in Azure resource explore.As i am only able to get list of resources under it

Comment: While Reproing the Scenario, I figured there is a different way to get the logs in JSON Format using Powershell.  Try using ConvertFrom-JSON in powershell Cmd.  Also please look at this doc for more reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/view-activity-logs#powershell